# How to Integrate Google Analytics (PageSpeed and Pageview both) for Ajax Loaded Pages?

Tags: javascript, ajax, performance, web, google-analytics

I am having a web application which runs completely on Ajax Loaded pages (For fast browsing). I integrated Google Analytics but it's not tracking speed of my Ajax Requests. Can anyone please tell me how to track speed? So, that I can tweak my ajax loaded pages as per requirements.

I've seen some people were suggesting to use `ga('send','pagespeed')` but I don't know how to implement such `ga` requests because of low-quality documentations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create two Custom Metrics with the scope `hit` and the formatting `integer`:

- `metric1` for "AJAX load times"
- `metric2` for "AJAX page views"

When the request is sent, start a timer:

```
var ajaxLoadTimeStart = Date.now();
```

When the response is received, end the timer:

```
var ajaxLoadTimeEnd = (Date.now() - ajaxLoadTimeStart)/1000;
```

Then send a new `page view` with the AJAX metrics:

```
ga('send', 'pageview', {
  'metric1': ajaxLoadTimeEnd,
  'metric2': 1
});
```